# Google StreetView Different Results in Browser

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am writing a small page to display locations on Google Maps. What I was aiming at was a pushpin for each location that I can click on and it will popup with a steetview of that address.

I have got all the code working but I am getting streetviews for addresses different to the addresses I am sending.

For example.

When I search for "Edwards Buildbase, Scotland Road, Market Harborough, LE16 8AX" in a browser, Google returns a streetview right outside the premises! Perfect! Just what I wanted!

https://www.google.co.uk/maps/preview#!q=Edwards+Buildbase%2C+Scotland+Road%2C+Market+Harborough+LE16+8AX&data=!1m8!1m3!1d3!2d-0.913338!3d52.470683!2m2!1f336.21!2f90!4f75!2m7!1e1!2m2!1snk_a1aOLxAGVE10CAKadLw!2e0!5m2!1snk_a1aOLxAGVE10CAKadLw!2e0!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x487771173d853741%3A0x9eebe36787bc4b78!3m8!1m3!1d8924!2d-0.913338!3d52.470683!3m2!1i1280!2i705!4f13.1!4m2!3d52.470992!4d-0.913562&fid=5

But, in my code, what I do is...

Geocode the address "Edwards Buildbase, Scotland Road, Market Harborough, LE16 8AX" and then tell the steetview that the lat/longs it should go to are the results....

And I end up with different streetviews!

This is my geocode function

```
var address = kmlEvent.featureData.name + ", " + kmlEvent.featureData.description;
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
                var panoramaOptions = {
                    position: latlng,
                    pov: {
                        heading: 34,
                        pitch: 10
                    }
                };
```

This is what I end up with when I click on Edwards Buildbase...

[image: This is what I get]

This is what I see in a browser...

[image]

I am guessing that because I am geocoding the address and then telling the streetview to focus on a lat/long there is a difference.

This is my demo site if you want to have a closer look at the code

http://googlemap.azurewebsites.net/

Does anyone know the best way to get the images being returned from the browser search please?

Any help would be appreciated!

Trev

Comment: Is it possible that your latlng data is not correct for that address: red marker is little nort-east from the location with the address you are looking for (blue marker)?

Comment: @AntoJurkovic yes. that is true. the blue markers were the addresses geocoded by Bing maps and are in the KML data. But I don't actually use those any more to do the streetview as they seemed even less accurate. At the moment I am taking the name of the business combined with it's address and geocoding that with Google and then sending those Google Lat/Longs to the Google Streetview. I was hoping that lat/longs geocoded by google would match better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address in you are geocoding is: "Edwards Buildbase, Scotland Road, Market Harborough, LE16 8AX", that returns a location for "Scotland Road, Market Harborough, Leicestershire LE16, UK" (52.4726594, -0.9118068000000221), which is not what you are looking for.

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Edwards%20Buildbase,%20Scotland%20Road,%20Market%20Harborough,%20LE16%208AX&geocode=1

If you use the Places API (Edwards Buildbase is not an address, it is a place), it returns a better result (52.470992, -0.9135619999999562):

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Edwards%20Buildbase,%20Scotland%20Road,%20Market%20Harborough,%20LE16%208AX&place=1&type=sat

Another option would be to use "17 Scotland Road, Market Harborough, Leicestershire LE16 8AX, UK"

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=17%20Scotland%20Road,%20Market%20Harborough,%20Leicestershire%20LE16%208AX,%20UK&geocode=1&type=sat

However, you would probably be better off correcting the coordinates in the KML and using those for the streetview, as both the places API and the geocoding service are subject to rate limits and a quota.